# Properly escape newlines in javascript json strings

Tags: javascript, json

I have a really long JSON String in JavaScript. It has several \n in it, which need to be escaped on clientside with:

```
replace(/\n/g, '\\n');
```

The Problem now is, that this `replace()` adds an extra newline at the end of my JSON string which I don't want (result is that my split("\n") will produce an extra line which is empty and invalid. So, how can I properly handle this? How can I properly escape that String without breaking its structure while `split("\n")` remains functional in the end?

Current string structure is something like: "testdata\ntestdata\ntestdata" etc.

EDIT: edit because I seem to not have given enough info:

1. Client receives a string from the server
2. This string is a JSON String and pretty long. Several sections in this string are divided by "\n"
3. On Clientside I need to perform split("\n") on the string to split it into exactly 50 rows. However I get 51, because an extra \n is added at the end after I escape the string
4. So, I only receive the data in e.data, then perform `replace(/\n/g, '\\n');` and after that perform split("\n") on it. That's all.
5. How do I prevent the split() from breaking because of my regex?

I hope this explains my problem better.

Comment: we can't guess at the code that is doing this...where's your code?

Comment: David Thomas: edited post. Without code tag the replace() params were wrong...

Comment: @charlietfl: My code is this: replace(/\n/g, '\\n');

Comment: Why do you need to re-escape all newlines? What is the purpose?

Comment: @DavidThomas I didn't change the code, I just used the code formatting tool...

Comment: @Shiuyin that is only one tiny snippet. We have no idea where you use this, or why? The really big question is why?

Comment: @DavidThomas OK, well sorry, that was not my intent.  Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @charlietfl: I hope my edit above explains it better? ..

Comment: It sounds like the problem is not with your regex. The newline at the end is there from the start. When you double escape it, you're just double escaping a newline that already exists. Use `String.trim()` remove trailing whitespace at the beginning and end of the string (including newlines).

Comment: If you need 50 can't you parse to array first and if length is over 50 remove those elements from array? Or modify server output. Still not 100% clear what is causing the issue that JSON isn't valid when delivered

Comment: Better still would be to send the JSON string as an array from the start. It is JSON, after all.

Comment: I think if you are trying to split a JSON string by newlines you're doing something wrong from the beginning. You should `JSON.parse()` it, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `replace` call if all you want to do is split a newline-separated string. The code sample below trims any leading or trailing whitespace (including newlines) and splits on `\n`.  Note that `trim` was added in ECMAScript 5.1 and is not supported in some older browsers.  See this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) for more information.

```js
function splitNewlineSeparatedString (s) {
    return s.trim().split("\n");
}

console.log(splitNewlineSeparatedString("testdata\ntestdata\ntestdata\n\n\n"));
```